# Times font and packages for lithuanian

Tags: fonts

I cannot get Times font when I use pslatex and packages for lithuanian language at the same time (font remains as default), how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\begin{document}
My text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `mathptmx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lithuanian setting that's declared by `\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}` requires fonts set up for the `L7x` encoding and the fonts provided by the (obsolete) package `pslatex` aren't.

You can obtain Times by

```
\usepackage{tgtermes}
```

If you also need math, then `\usepackage{mathptmx}` should be issued before the line above.

The `tgtermes` package will use the TeX Gyre Termes font, which is a clone of Times (in the Linotype variant, I'm afraid).